# rails f.label error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`<%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>` is causing the following error.

```
undefined method `extract_label_options!' for #<ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag:0x20ce700>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
<%= f.label :first_name %>
```

which means

```
<label for="person_first_name">First name</label>:
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `form_for`, or paste your whole form here.